# How to make background shown on pulldown Black instead of white on safari mobile web with React

Tags: html, css, reactjs

[image]

In the picture above I pressed on the screen down on an iPhone 11 coded as a fullstack React webapp. Is there a way to make the white background that is revealed into a black color. This only happens if you scroll down on an already fully black screen. The white section is not a white box that I've hardcoded.

Answer (score 0):

Try styling the `html` and `body` elements with a black background.

```css
html, body {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

Comment: the html background-color did make the background color black if I overflow the vertical content but this does not work for when I pulldown on the screen